# How to install modules on the shell automatically on repl.it using python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit, mo

I am making a discord bot, for this I needed to make buttons for an embed, and to do that I needed to import a library. Once I imported it in the code replit would say that there is [no module named discord_slash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWJen.png), so I went into the [shell and used pip install discord-py-interactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94YTI.png), and then the code worked, however each time I leave replit and come back to it I need to repeat this process for the code to work. How to make it so that it automatically installs that library when I run the program?

[before installing:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWJen.png)
Nothing was changed in the code. Just used pip to download it in the shell.
[After installing:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94YTI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. Use the packages system on replit to install the module, then it will be installed permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Use packages too install modules. It is on the left of your screen.